# LARAVEL - Correct way to insert data in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a question about how to structure the code the right way when I add data to related tables.

I have this, and it works. But is that the correct way? 
Seems a bit messy

Relations tables:

Property:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('imoveis', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('tipoImovel_id');
            $table->string('finalidade',20);
            $table->string('titulo',100);
            $table->date('data')->nullable();
            $table->integer('concelho_id');
            $table->string('freguesia',50);
            $table->string('rua',150);
            $table->decimal('long', 10, 7)->nullable();
            $table->decimal('lat', 10, 7)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('destaque');
            $table->boolean('estado')->default(true);
            $table->string('descricao',500);
            $table->string('preco',40);
            $table->integer('empresa_id')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

House:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('moradias', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('imovel_id');
            $table->integer('nrPisosConstrucao');
            $table->integer('nrQuartos');
            $table->integer('nrWcs');
            $table->integer('areaConstrucao');
            $table->integer('areaTerreno');
            $table->smallInteger('anoConstrucao');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Photos

```
 Schema::create('fotos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('imovel_id');
            $table->string('nome',15);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And to insert a House i have that function in HouseController, and works... but seem kind a messy...

```
public function create(){

        //save Property(BASE)
        $this->imovel->titulo = Input::get('titulo');
        $this->imovel->finalidade = Input::get('finalidade');
        $this->imovel->data =  Input::get('data');
        $this->imovel->concelho_id = Input::get('concelho');
        $this->imovel->freguesia = Input::get('freguesia');
        $this->imovel->rua = Input::get('rua');
        $this->imovel->long = Input::get('longitude');
        $this->imovel->lat = Input::get('latitude');
        $this->imovel->descricao = Input::get('descricao');
        $this->imovel->preco = Input::get('preco');
        $this->imovel->tipoimovel_id = 1; //Empresa- 
        $this->imovel->save();

        //save House
        $moradia= new Moradia;
        $moradia->imovel_id = $this->imovel->id;
        $moradia->nrQuartos = Input::get('nrQuartos');
        $moradia->nrPisosConstrucao = Input::get('nrPisos');
        $moradia->nrWcs = Input::get('nrWcs');
        $moradia->areaConstrucao = Input::get('areaConstrucao');
        $moradia->areaTerreno = Input::get('areaTerreno');
        $moradia->anoConstrucao = Input::get('anoConstrucao');
        $moradia->save();

        //upload photos
          $files = Input::file('images');
          $contaFotos=0;

           foreach ($files as $file) {
            $rules = array('file' => 'required'); //'required|mimes:png,gif,jpeg,txt,pdf,doc'
            $validator = Validator::make(array('file'=> $file), $rules);
            if($validator->passes()){
             $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
              $destinationPath = 'uploads';  //folder 
              $filename = $this->imovel->id . '_'. $contaFotos++ . '.' . $extension;
              $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

              // SAVE DB
              $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();   
              $foto= new Foto();
              $foto->imovel_id = $this->imovel->id;
              $foto->nome = $filename;
              $this->imovel->fotos()->save($foto);
            }
          }

          return view('admin.imoveis.index');


    }
```

Models Relation in Property

```
public function atributos(){
    //se for moradia
    if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 1) {
        return $this->hasOne(Moradia::class);
    }
    //se for apartamento
    else if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 2) {
        return $this->hasOne(Apartamento::class);
    }
    //se for loja
    else if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 3) {
        return $this->hasOne(Loja::class);
    }
    //se for armazem
    else if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 4) {
        return $this->hasOne(Armazem::class);
    }
    //se for terreno para construção
    else if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 5) {
        return $this->hasOne(TerrenoConstrucao::class);
    }
    // se for terreno para outros fins
    else if ($this->tipoimovel_id == 6) {
        return $this->hasOne(TerrenoOutrosFins::class);
    }
```

Comment: It's correct by all means, but there are nicer way to do some things. Validation is usually put in [requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation). You could attach attributes with [`$this->imovel->fill(Input::all())`](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill) method (you'll have to deal with mass assignement though). Your migrations are great though. Depending on version you're using not all of these might apply though. Which version are you using?

Comment: last version of laravel. but i have more types os property, like apartment, shop. I have to do same thing in ApartmentConstroller and ShopController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically depends on your relationships, The following way works both for `one to many` and `one to one`.

```
    $moradia= new Moradia;
    //Removed insertion for id from here.
    $moradia->nrQuartos = Input::get('nrQuartos');
    $moradia->nrPisosConstrucao = Input::get('nrPisos');
    $moradia->nrWcs = Input::get('nrWcs');
    $moradia->areaConstrucao = Input::get('areaConstrucao');
    $moradia->areaTerreno = Input::get('areaTerreno');
    $moradia->anoConstrucao = Input::get('anoConstrucao');
    // This is what i added
    $this->imovel->atributos() -> save($moradia);
```

And same is the case for image.

Comment: use `atributos()` in `$moradia->atributos()->save($moradia);`

Comment: Edited the answer, I added `()` to `atributos` so now its `atributos()`.

Comment: instead of  `$moradia->relationShipName->save($moradia);` should be `$imovel->relationShipName->save($moradia);` or `$this->imovel->relationShipName->save($moradia);`?

Comment: It will be `$moradia->atributos()->save($moradia);`.

Comment: give me an error _Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::atributos()_

Comment: Works with `$this->imovel->atributos() -> save($moradia);`

Comment: Ohh okay, Pleased it worked, My bad there. If it work please accept the answer.

Comment: but i have to create this method for other types os property's? and put the validation here too?

Comment: I suggest your validation should stay in your controller, And for other types or properties, it can be done within this method but need some conditions. But if the properties are not too many you should create separate for each.